# Cannot extract text value in XML CLOB in a table in PL SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, clob

I have a form created in XML and following data is stored as XML_CLOB,

```
<entry-form caption="SECTION B SOCIAL AND ENVIRONMENTAL STATUS OF THE PROJECT" data-key="sec B" show-caption="true" is-listing-grid="true" alignment="left" shade="bold" is-underline="false" __id="230"/*>
<dropdown label="1. Current status/ stage of the project" data-key="Current status stage of the project" multiple="false" mandatory="false" is-online-field="0" online-field-text="No" __id="281">
<option value="0" text="Design" is-highlight="false" __id="282" />
<option value="1" text="Construction" is-highlight="false" __id="283" />
<option value="2" text="Commissioning" is-highlight="false" __id="325" />
<option value="3" text="Operating" is-highlight="false" __id="326" />
```

I need to extract text value of each option above (Example Text value of option "0" is "Design".

I'm using SQL Developer as a beginner and please help me build a syntax to extract the above.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the source code of your procedure as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) -  [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: But this data is not a valid XML unfortuantely